# Cs50 pset1 Credit

Tags: c, cs50

I am very new to coding before two weeks ago writing a program to me was akin to magic. I have been racking my brain for days as to the most efficient way to solve this problem. Finally I decided to start writing and with the use of smaller simpler programs aimed at tackling each aspect of this problem separately; I arrived at the solution posted in my code. My program works as intended but I feel like I didn't use the most efficient route.

My question is: what are some tips and tricks you can give me to make this program more efficient i.e. time to write or lines of code. Also I would appreciate any suggestion as to how one can become more efficient other than just practicing i.e. any books or processes you'd recommend. I have submitted this version of my code to the cs50 system for grading so I'm not looking for you to do my HW for me I just want to know what strategies or different ways of thinking could achieve the same results.

Thank you in advance for taking the time to instruct me

here is the code:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    long cc;

    do
    {
        cc = get_long("number: ");

    } while (cc < 0);

    int checksum = 0;

    {
        // 2nd digit ** henceforth all digit placement from right to left //
        checksum += (((cc / 10) % 10) * 2) / 10;
        checksum += (((cc / 10) % 10) * 2) % 10;
    }
    {
        // 4th digit //
        checksum += (((cc / 1000) % 10) * 2) / 10;
        checksum += (((cc / 1000) % 10) * 2) % 10;
    }
    {
        // 6th digit  //
        checksum += (((cc / 100000) % 10) * 2) / 10;
        checksum += (((cc / 100000) % 10) * 2) % 10;
    }
    {
        // 8th digit //
        checksum += (((cc / 10000000) % 10) * 2) / 10;
        checksum += (((cc / 10000000) % 10) * 2) % 10;
    }
    {
        // 10th digit //
        checksum += (((cc / 1000000000) % 10) * 2) / 10;
        checksum += (((cc / 1000000000) % 10) * 2) % 10;
    }
    {
        // 12th digit //
        checksum += (((cc / 100000000000) % 10) * 2) / 10;
        checksum += (((cc / 100000000000) % 10) * 2) % 10;
    }
    {
        // 14th digit //
        checksum += (((cc / 10000000000000) % 10) * 2) / 10;
        checksum += (((cc / 10000000000000) % 10) * 2) % 10;
    }
    {
        // 16th digit //
        checksum += (((cc / 1000000000000000) % 10) * 2) / 10;
        checksum += (((cc / 1000000000000000) % 10) * 2) % 10;
    }
    {
        //  1st digit //
        checksum += cc % 10;
    }
    {
        // 3rd digit //
        checksum += (cc / 100) % 10;
    }
    {
        // 5th digit //
        checksum += (cc / 10000) % 10;
    }
    {
        // 7th digit //
        checksum += (cc / 1000000) % 10;
    }
    {
        // 9th digit //
        checksum += (cc / 100000000) % 10;
    }
    {
        // 11th digit //
        checksum += (cc / 10000000000) % 10;
    }
    {
        // 13th digit //
        checksum += (cc / 1000000000000) % 10;
    }
    {
        // 15th digit //
        checksum += (cc / 100000000000000) % 10;
    }

    if (checksum % 10 == 0 && (cc / 1000000000000000) % 10 == 5
            && (cc / 100000000000000) % 10 >= 1
            && (cc / 100000000000000) % 10 <= 5)
    {
        printf("MASTERCARD\n");
    }
    else if (checksum % 10 == 0 && (cc / 1000000000000) % 10 == 4)
    {
        printf("VISA\n");
    }
    else if (checksum % 10 == 0 && (cc / 1000000000000000) % 10 == 4)
    {
        printf("VISA\n");
    }
    else if (checksum % 10 == 0 && (cc / 100000000000000) % 10 == 3
            && (cc / 10000000000000) % 10 == 4)
    {
        printf("AMEX\n");
    }
    else if (checksum % 10 == 0 && (cc / 100000000000000) % 10 == 3
            && (cc / 10000000000000) % 10 == 7)
    {
        printf("AMEX\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: IMHO, your program is too small to gain any significant execution time by optimizing it.  Most benefits from optimization come from reducing requirements and optimizing the algorithm.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews got it thanks.

Comment: Can you see how you could make a loop or two to extract the digits and add up the checksum? You don't need to write out essentially the same code 15 times.

Comment: Try looking through your code for any patterns.  See if you can optimize those (such as making partial calculations and storing in temporary variables).

Comment: BTW, digit manipulation is often easier by treating the number as a string.  You can get the value of a digit with:  `int digit_value = number_as_string[x] - '0';`  IMHO, a lot better than dividing and using remainder.

Comment: As an opposite opinion, if you have an integer that you want to extract digits from then I do strongly prefer division rather than converting it into a string so that you can read digits from the string. However a credit card number isn't something that needs to be an integer - you never add or subtract credit card numbers - so it does make sense to read it in as a string not an int or long in this case, and read digits from the string as Thomas suggests. You may then have to check that all the characters in the string are digits though, and maybe trim leading / trailing spaces too.

Comment: Please see my answer below. I developed a more efficitent algorithm. And, in my opinion it is also more readable, because we get rid of all the big numbers. Additionally, I think you need also the number of digits. This is also in the specification. I added this also in my below answer.

Comment: Thank you all for all the answers and for your time, specially that bit about treating the number as a string. I had assumed that strings can only be letters and and sentences ect...  I will change my notes accordingly. Again thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm is a little bit hard to read. There are many repetitions and lot of big numbers with many 0s in it. I would therefore propose a different approach. You can look at each single digit in a loop. And, you can also do the whole checksum calculation in one step.

I will show you how to do and explain the algorithm behind it.

BTW. Chosing the right algorithm is always the key for success.

So, first we need to think on how we can extract digits from a number. This can be done in a loop by repeating the follwoing steps:

1. Perform a modulo 10 division to get a digit
2. Do a integer division by 10
3. Repeat

Let us look at the example 1234.

- Step 1 will get the 4  -- (1234 % 10 = 4)
- Step 2 will convert original number into 123 -- (1234 / 10 = 123)
- Step 1 will get the 3  -- (123 % 10 = 3)
- Step 2 will convert the previous number into 12 -- (123 / 10 = 12)
- Step 1 will get the 2  -- (12 % 10 = 2)
- Step 2 will convert the previous number into 1 -- (12 / 10 = 1)
- Step 1 will get the 1  -- (1 % 10 = 1)
- Step 2 will convert the previous number into 0 -- (1 / 10 = 0)

Then the loop stops. Additionally we can observe that the loop stops, when the resulting divided becomes 0. And, we see addtionally that the number of loop executions is equal to the number of digits in the number. But this is somehow obvious.

OK, then let us look, what we learned so far

```
while (creditCardNumber > 0) {

    unsigned int digit = creditCardNumber % 10;
    creditCardNumber /= 10;

    ++countOfDigits;
}
```

This will get all digits and count them.

Good. Lets go to next step.

For later validation and comparison purpose we need to get the most significant digit (the first digit) and the second most significant digit (the second digit) of the number.

For this, we define 2 variables which will hold the number. We simply assign the current evaluated digit (and override it in each loop execution) to the "mostSignificantDigit". At the end of the loop, we will have it in our desired variable.

For the "secondMostSignificantDigit" we will simple copy the "old" or "previous" value of the "mostSignificantDigit", before assigning a new value to "mostSignificantDigit". With that, we will always have both values available.

The loop looks now like this:

```
while (creditCardNumber > 0) {

    const unsigned int digit = creditCardNumber % 10;

    secondMostSignificantDigit = mostSignificantDigit;
    mostSignificantDigit = digit;

    creditCardNumber /= 10;

    ++countOfDigits;
}
```

---

OK, now we come to the maybe more complex part. The cheksum. The calculation method is.

1. Start with the least significant (the last) digit
2. Do not multiply the digit, which is equivalent with multiplying it with 1, and add it to the checksum
3. Goto the next digit. Multiply it by 2. If the result is greater than 10, then get again the single digits and add both digits to the checksum
4. Repeat

So, the secret is, to analyze the somehow cryptic specification, given [here](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/1/credit/). If we start with the last digit, we do not multiply it, the next digit will be multiplied, the next not and so on and so on.

To "not multiply" is the same as multiplying by 1. This means: In the loop we need to multiply alternating with 1 or with 2.

How to get alternating numbers in a loop? The algorithm for that is fairly simple. If you need alternating numbers, lets say, x,y,x,y,x,y,x..., Then, build the sum of x and y and perform the subtratcion "value = sum - value". Example:
We need alternating values 1 and 2. The sum is 3. To get the next value, we subtract the current value from the sum.

- initial value = 1
- sum = 3
- current value = initial value = 1
- next value = 3 - 1 = 2. Current value = 2
- next value = 3 - 2 = 1. Current value = 1
- next value = 3 - 1 = 2. Current value = 2
- next value = 3 - 2 = 1. Current value = 1
- next value = 3 - 1 = 2. Current value = 2
- next value = 3 - 2 = 1. Current value = 1
- . . .

Good, now we understand, how to make alternating values.

Next, If we multiply a digit with 2, then the maximum result maybe a 2 digit value. We get the single digits with a modulo and an integer division by 10.

And, now important, it does not matter, if we multiply or not, because, if we do not multiply, then the upper digit will always be 0. And this will not contribute to the sum.

With all that, we can always do a multiplication and always split the result into 2 digits (many of them having the upper digit 0).

The result will be:

```
checkSum += (digit * multiplier) % 10 + (digit * multiplier) / 10;
multiplier = 3 - multiplier;
```

An astonishingly simple formula.

Next, if we know C or C++ we also know that a multiplication with 2 can be done very efficiently with a bit shift left. And, additionally, a "no-multiplication" can be done with a bit shift 0. That is extremely efficient and faster than multiplication.

- `x * 1`   is identical with `x << 0`
- `x * 2`   is identical with `x << 1`

For the final result we will use this mechanism, alternate the multiplier between 0 and 1 and do shifts.

This will give us a very effective checksum calculation.

At the end of the program, we will use all gathered values and compare them to the specification.

Thsi will lead to:

```
int main() {

    // Get the credit card number. Unfortunately I do not know CS50. I use the C++ standard iostream lib.
    // Please replace the following 4 lines with your CS50 equivalent
    unsigned long long creditCardNumber;
    std::cout << "Enter credit card number: ";
    std::cin >> creditCardNumber;
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    // We need to count the number of digits for validation
    unsigned int countOfDigits = 0;

    // Here we will calculate the checksum
    unsigned int checkSum = 0;

    // We need to multiply digits with 1 or with 2
    unsigned int multiplier = 0;

    // For validation purposes we need the most significant 2 digits
    unsigned int mostSignificantDigit = 0;
    unsigned int secondMostSignificantDigit = 0;

    // Now we get all digits from the credit card number in a loop
    while (creditCardNumber > 0) {

        // Get the least significant digits (for 1234 it will be 4)
        const unsigned int digit = creditCardNumber % 10;

        // Now we have one digit more. In the end we will have the number of all digits
        ++countOfDigits;

        // Simply remember the most significant digits
        secondMostSignificantDigit = mostSignificantDigit;
        mostSignificantDigit = digit;

        // Calculate the checksum
        checkSum += (digit << multiplier) % 10 + (digit << multiplier) / 10;

        // Multiplier for next loop 
        multiplier = 1 - multiplier;

        creditCardNumber /= 10;
    }
    // Get the least significant digit of the checksum
    checkSum %= 10;

    // Validate all calculated values and show the result
    if ((0 == checkSum) &&                  // Checksum must be correct AND
        (15 == countOfDigits) &&            // Count of digits must be correct AND
        ((3 == mostSignificantDigit) &&     // Most significant digits must be correct 
        ((4 == secondMostSignificantDigit) || (7 == secondMostSignificantDigit)))) {
        std::cout << "AMEX\n";
    }
    else if ((0 == checkSum) &&             // Checksum must be correct AND
        (16 == countOfDigits) &&            // Count of digits must be correct AND
        ((5 == mostSignificantDigit) &&     // Most significant digits must be correct
        ((secondMostSignificantDigit > 0) && (secondMostSignificantDigit < 6)))) {
        std::cout << "MASTERCARD\n";
    }
    else if ((0 == checkSum) &&             // Checksum must be correct AND
        ((16 == countOfDigits) || (13 == countOfDigits)) && // Count of digits must be correct AND
        ((4 == mostSignificantDigit))) {    // Most significant digit must be correct
        std::cout << "VISA\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "INVALID\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What we learn with this example, is integer division and modulo division and the smart usage of the [identity element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) for binary operations.

In case of questions, please ask

---

---

Just to be complete, I will show you a C++ solution, based on a `std::string` and using modern C++ elements and algorithms.

For example, the whole checksum calculation will be done with one statement. The whole program does not contain any loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <numeric>

int main() {

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Get user input
    // Inform user, what to do. Enter a credit card number. We are a little tolerant with the input format
    std::cout << "\nPlease enter a credit card number:\t";

    // Get the number, in any format from the user
    std::string creditCardNumber{};
    std::getline(std::cin, creditCardNumber);

    // Remove the noise, meaning, all non digits from the credit card number
    creditCardNumber = std::regex_replace(creditCardNumber, std::regex(R"(\D)"), "");

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Calculate checksum
    unsigned int checksum = std::accumulate(creditCardNumber.rbegin(), creditCardNumber.rend(), 0U,
        [multiplier = 1U](const unsigned int sum, const char digit) mutable -> unsigned int {
        multiplier = 1 - multiplier; unsigned int value = digit - '0';
        return sum + ((value << multiplier) % 10) + ((value << multiplier) / 10); });

    // We are only interested in the lowest digit
    checksum %= 10;

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Validation and output
    if ((0 == checksum) &&                      // Checksum must be correct AND
        (15 == creditCardNumber.length()) &&    // Count of digits must be correct AND
        (('3' == creditCardNumber[0]) &&        // Most significant digits must be correct 
        (('4' == creditCardNumber[1]) || ('7' == creditCardNumber[1])))) {
        std::cout << "AMEX\n";
    }
    else if ((0 == checksum) &&                 // Checksum must be correct AND
        (16 == creditCardNumber.length()) &&    // Count of digits must be correct AND
        (('5' == creditCardNumber[0]) &&        // Most significant digits must be correct
        ((creditCardNumber[1] > '0') && (creditCardNumber[1] < '6')))) {
        std::cout << "MASTERCARD\n";
    }
    else if ((0 == checksum) &&                 // Checksum must be correct AND
        ((16 == creditCardNumber.length()) || (13 == creditCardNumber.length())) && // Count of digits must be correct AND
        (('4' == creditCardNumber[0]))) {       // Most significant digit must be correct
        std::cout << "VISA\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "INVALID\n";
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: I understand your first example. As for the second I'm having trouble understanding the setup part but i think that has to do more with my lack familiarity w/ c++. I did a little research on identity elements for binary operations and will try to remember as i can see how useful it is for problems like this. I want thank you so much for your detailed explanation it is exactly what I was looking for.