# Error with two credit card numbers. Identifies the number as the wrong credit card type

Tags: c++, cs50

These are my current errors, I think I did something wrong with the maths but everything I tried didn't work.

Ps: Sorry if my question's formatting is bad, first time using stackflow.

:) credit.c exists

:) credit.c compiles

:) identifies 378282246310005 as AMEX

:) identifies 371449635398431 as AMEX

:) identifies 5555555555554444 as MASTERCARD

:) identifies 5105105105105100 as MASTERCARD

:) identifies 4111111111111111 as VISA

:) identifies 4012888888881881 as VISA

:) identifies 4222222222222 as VISA

:) identifies 1234567890 as INVALID

:) identifies 369421438430814 as INVALID

:) identifies 4062901840 as INVALID

:) identifies 5673598276138003 as INVALID

:( identifies 4111111111111113 as INVALID
expected "INVALID\n", not "VISA\n"

:( identifies 4222222222223 as INVALID
expected "INVALID\n", not "VISA\n"

````
#include <cs50.h>

#include <math.h>

// Prompt user for credit card number
int main(void)
{
    long credit_card, credit_number;
    do
    {
        credit_card = get_long("Enter credit card number: ");
    }
    while (credit_card < 0);
    
    credit_number = credit_card;
    

    // Calculate total number of digits
    int count = (credit_number == 0) ? 1  : (log10(credit_number) + 1);
    int summation = 0;

    while (credit_number == 0)
    {
        int x = credit_number % 10; summation += x;
        int y = 2 * ((credit_number / 10) % 10);
        int r = (y % 10) + floor((y / 10) % 10); summation += r; credit_number /= 100;
    }

    string card;
    // Identify which card type you get after inputing your credit card number
    int test = cc / pow(10, count - 2);
    if ((count == 13 || count == 16) && test / 10 == 4)
    {
        card = "VISA";
    }
    else if (count == 16  && test >= 51 && test <= 55)
    {
        card = "MASTERCARD";
    }
    else if (count == 15 && (test == 34 || test == 37))
    {
        card = "AMEX";
    }
    else
    {
        card = "INVALID";
    }

    // Final verification
    if (sum % 10 == 0)
    {
        printf("%s\n", card);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }

}```
````

Comment: Are your numbers not too big for a `long`?

Comment: Avoid *"float functions"* as `pow`/`floor` for integer computation.

Comment: A decimal 16-digit number needs ~50 bits. A `long` most likely has 32. Treat the input as a string of digits instead of a number.

Comment: a credit card number is an ID, it is unlikely that you need to do any arithmetics with it, so a `std::string` (plus checking for valid digits) is more appropriate

Comment: CS50 is a course in C, not C++. If you try to learn C++ from it, you're going to become very confused.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is maybe not fully correct. I would therefore propose a different approach. You can look at each single digit in a loop. And, you can also do the whole checksum calculation in one step.

I will show you how to do and explain the algorithm behind it.

BTW. Chosing the right algorithm is always the key for success.

So, first we need to think on how we can extract digits from a number. This can be done in a loop by repeating the follwoing steps:

1. Perform a modulo 10 division to get a digit
2. Do a integer division by 10
3. Repeat

Let us look at the example 1234.

- Step 1 will get the 4  -- (1234 % 10 = 4)
- Step 2 will convert original number into 123 -- (1234 / 10 = 123)
- Step 1 will get the 3  -- (123 % 10 = 3)
- Step 2 will convert the previous number into 12 -- (123 / 10 = 12)
- Step 1 will get the 2  -- (12 % 10 = 2)
- Step 2 will convert the previous number into 1 -- (12 / 10 = 1)
- Step 1 will get the 1  -- (1 % 10 = 1)
- Step 2 will convert the previous number into 0 -- (1 / 10 = 0)

Then the loop stops. Additionally we can observe that the loop stops, when the resulting divided becomes 0. And, we see addtionally that the number of loop executions is equal to the number of digits in the number. But this is somehow obvious.

OK, then let us look, what we learned so far

```
while (creditCardNumber > 0) {

    unsigned int digit = creditCardNumber % 10;
    creditCardNumber /= 10;

    ++countOfDigits;
}
```

This will get all digits and count them.

Good. Lets go to next step.

For later validation and comparison purpose we need to get the most significant digit (the first digit) and the second most significant digit (the second digit) of the number.

For this, we define 2 variables which will hold the number. We simply assign the current evaluated digit (and override it in each loop execution) to the "mostSignificantDigit". At the end of the loop, we will have it in our desired variable.

For the "secondMostSignificantDigit" we will simple copy the "old" or "previous" value of the "mostSignificantDigit", before assigning a new value to "mostSignificantDigit". With that, we will always have both values available.

The loop looks now like this:

```
while (creditCardNumber > 0) {

    const unsigned int digit = creditCardNumber % 10;

    secondMostSignificantDigit = mostSignificantDigit;
    mostSignificantDigit = digit;

    creditCardNumber /= 10;

    ++countOfDigits;
}
```

---

OK, now we come to the maybe more complex part. The cheksum. The calculation method is.

1. Start with the least significant (the last) digit
2. Do not multiply the digit, which is equivalent with multiplying it with 1, and add it to the checksum
3. Goto the next digit. Multiply it by 2. If the result is greater than 10, then get again the single digits and add both digits to the checksum
4. Repeat

So, the secret is, to analyze the somehow cryptic specification, given [here](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/1/credit/). If we start with the last digit, we do not multiply it, the next digit will be multiplied, the next not and so on and so on.

To "not multiply" is the same as multiplying by 1. This means: In the loop we need to multiply alternating with 1 or with 2.

How to get alternating numbers in a loop? The algorithm for that is fairly simple. If you need alternating numbers, lets say, x,y,x,y,x,y,x..., Then, build the sum of x and y and perform the subtratcion "value = sum - value". Example:
We need alternating values 1 and 2. The sum is 3. To get the next value, we subtract the current value from the sum.

- initial value = 1
- sum = 3
- current value = initial value = 1
- next value = 3 - 1 = 2. Current value = 2
- next value = 3 - 2 = 1. Current value = 1
- next value = 3 - 1 = 2. Current value = 2
- next value = 3 - 2 = 1. Current value = 1
- next value = 3 - 1 = 2. Current value = 2
- next value = 3 - 2 = 1. Current value = 1
- . . .

Good, now we understand, how to make alternating values.

Next, If we multiply a digit with 2, then the maximum result maybe a 2 digit value. We get the single digits with a modulo and an integer division by 10.

And, now important, it does not matter, if we multiply or not, because, if we do not multiply, then the upper digit will always be 0. And this will not contribute to the sum.

With all that, we can always do a multiplication and always split the result into 2 digits (many of them having the upper digit 0).

The result will be:

```
checkSum += (digit * multiplier) % 10 + (digit * multiplier) / 10;
multiplier = 3 - multiplier;
```

An astonishingly simple formula.

Next, if we know C or C++ we also know that a multiplication with 2 can be done very efficiently with a bit shift left. And, additionally, a "no-multiplication" can be done with a bit shift 0. That is extremely efficient and faster than multiplication.

- `x * 1`   is identical with `x << 0`
- `x * 2`   is identical with `x << 1`

For the final result we will use this mechanism, alternate the multiplier between 0 and 1 and do shifts.

This will give us a very effective checksum calculation.

At the end of the program, we will use all gathered values and compare them to the specification.

Thsi will lead to:

```
int main() {

    // Get the credit card number. Unfortunately I do not know CS50. I use the C++ standard iostream lib.
    // Please replace the following 4 lines with your CS50 equivalent
    unsigned long long creditCardNumber;
    std::cout << "Enter credit card number: ";
    std::cin >> creditCardNumber;
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    // We need to count the number of digits for validation
    unsigned int countOfDigits = 0;

    // Here we will calculate the checksum
    unsigned int checkSum = 0;

    // We need to multiply digits with 1 or with 2
    unsigned int multiplier = 0;

    // For validation purposes we need the most significant 2 digits
    unsigned int mostSignificantDigit = 0;
    unsigned int secondMostSignificantDigit = 0;

    // Now we get all digits from the credit card number in a loop
    while (creditCardNumber > 0) {

        // Get the least significant digits (for 1234 it will be 4)
        const unsigned int digit = creditCardNumber % 10;
        
        // Now we have one digit more. In the end we will have the number of all digits
        ++countOfDigits;

        // Simply remember the most significant digits
        secondMostSignificantDigit = mostSignificantDigit;
        mostSignificantDigit = digit;

        // Calculate the checksum
        checkSum += (digit << multiplier) % 10 + (digit << multiplier) / 10;

        // Multiplier for next loop 
        multiplier = 1 - multiplier;

        creditCardNumber /= 10;
    }
    // Get the least significant digit of the checksum
    checkSum %= 10;

    // Validate all calculated values and show the result
    if ((0 == checkSum) &&                  // Checksum must be correct AND
        (15 == countOfDigits) &&            // Count of digits must be correct AND
        ((3 == mostSignificantDigit) &&     // Most significant digits must be correct 
        ((4 == secondMostSignificantDigit) || (7 == secondMostSignificantDigit)))) {
        std::cout << "AMEX\n";
    }
    else if ((0 == checkSum) &&             // Checksum must be correct AND
        (16 == countOfDigits) &&            // Count of digits must be correct AND
        ((5 == mostSignificantDigit) &&     // Most significant digits must be correct
        ((secondMostSignificantDigit > 0) && (secondMostSignificantDigit < 6)))) {
        std::cout << "MASTERCARD\n";
    }
    else if ((0 == checkSum) &&             // Checksum must be correct AND
        ((16 == countOfDigits) || (13 == countOfDigits)) && // Count of digits must be correct AND
        ((4 == mostSignificantDigit))) {    // Most significant digit must be correct
        std::cout << "VISA\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "INVALID\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What we learn with this example, is integer division and modulo division and the smart usage of the [identity element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) for binary operations.

In case of questions, please ask

---

---

Just to be complete, I will show you a C++ solution, based on a `std::string` and using modern C++ elements and algorithms.

For example, the whole checksum calculation will be done with one statement. The whole program does not contain any loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <numeric>

int main() {

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Get user input
    // Inform user, what to do. Enter a credit card number. We are a little tolerant with the input format
    std::cout << "\nPlease enter a credit card number:\t";

    // Get the number, in any format from the user
    std::string creditCardNumber{};
    std::getline(std::cin, creditCardNumber);

    // Remove the noise, meaning, all non digits from the credit card number
    creditCardNumber = std::regex_replace(creditCardNumber, std::regex(R"(\D)"), "");

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Calculate checksum
    unsigned int checksum = std::accumulate(creditCardNumber.rbegin(), creditCardNumber.rend(), 0U,
        [multiplier = 1U](const unsigned int sum, const char digit) mutable -> unsigned int {
        multiplier = 1 - multiplier; unsigned int value = digit - '0';
        return sum + ((value << multiplier) % 10) + ((value << multiplier) / 10); });

    // We are only interested in the lowest digit
    checksum %= 10;

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Validation and output
    if ((0 == checksum) &&                      // Checksum must be correct AND
        (15 == creditCardNumber.length()) &&    // Count of digits must be correct AND
        (('3' == creditCardNumber[0]) &&        // Most significant digits must be correct 
        (('4' == creditCardNumber[1]) || ('7' == creditCardNumber[1])))) {
        std::cout << "AMEX\n";
    }
    else if ((0 == checksum) &&                 // Checksum must be correct AND
        (16 == creditCardNumber.length()) &&    // Count of digits must be correct AND
        (('5' == creditCardNumber[0]) &&        // Most significant digits must be correct
        ((creditCardNumber[1] > '0') && (creditCardNumber[1] < '6')))) {
        std::cout << "MASTERCARD\n";
    }
    else if ((0 == checksum) &&                 // Checksum must be correct AND
        ((16 == creditCardNumber.length()) || (13 == creditCardNumber.length())) && // Count of digits must be correct AND
        (('4' == creditCardNumber[0]))) {       // Most significant digit must be correct
        std::cout << "VISA\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "INVALID\n";
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: this is a recycle of an existing answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62356725/4117728. It isnt plagiarism (I was suspecting it, but actually not from you, nevertheless I checked), but if this question has the same answer as the other then it should be flagged as duplicate rather than duplicating the answer

Comment: "BTW. Chosing the right algorithm is always the key for success. " actually thats a little off. The main problem in OPs code seems to be the type of the ID rather than the algorithm

Comment: I am not a mod, I am just a regular user who cares a lot about plagiarism and this answer was a little suspicious. As I already said, it definitely isnt plagiarism, and I dont know what would be best in such case. When I wrote "then it should be flagged as duplicate" I should have written "maybe it should be flagged ..."

Comment: btw you can recognize mods by the diamond next to the user name.

Comment: I did see the same answer already in a different post, hence why I posted my question, but I believe after further investigation that my answer lies in Luhns algorithm, I seem to have it wrong. Another issue I have noticed after posting this is that the "=" at the "<= 55" is too much, making it "< 56" corrects my mistake with the MasterCard